# How to match URLs in Ruby 1.8.7 using Regex

Tags: python, ruby, regex

I'm doing a project which requires me to match URLs . I'm horrible at regex. But i believe the structure goes as follows -

- letters and symbols , except space that that can be repeated 1 to any number of times,
- immediately followed by a dot 0 or 1 times,
- followed by letters and symbols , except space, 1 to many times,
- followed by a dot " ." ,
- followed by a list of valid extensions (like com ,org,in (will be specified here))
- followed by a "/" 0 or 1 times

  - if 0, then immediately followed by space
  - if 1 , then words and symbols except

how do I form the regex for this

Comment: @AvinashRaj
This [Regex](http://rubular.com/r/Bqh38VDz50) i tried. Only to realise that it accepts string like that. Then I realised I can match the .com,.org,in and all..

Comment: Ruby uses perl style regexes, [the url spec](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt) is more difficult to regex than you might think. You may be better using one someone else has built for you like the answer suggested above if your not sure.

Comment: @ShaneQful doesnt take care of URLs like fb.me 9gag.com.
Just need to match URLs found in twitter and http://*.*.*/* <no spaces> and \*.\*.\*/* (no spaces)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried this [regex](http://rubular.com/r/ff3QDTbDlG) .  But epic fail in matching

Comment: why the python and ruby tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the URL's which satisfy the above criteria.

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\W\s_]+\.?[^\W\s_]+\.(?:com|org|me)(?:\/[^\W\s_]+)?
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/to1qBmOepb)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not suited very well to parse grammars and validate input. Regex is just meant for string pattern matching.

Use a parser for validating the syntax of a input, in your case try [ruby's URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html). It's part of the 1.8.7 default libary